# Sending UDP Commands to control LimitlessLED v6 Bridge

Tags: android, automation, udp, tasker, light

Good evening,
I already have many of the older lighting fixtures in my house set up and working with a v5 Bridge via Tasker. I now also have the newer fixtures (RGBWW/CW) which require the v6 Bridge which uses a different protocol (http://www.limitlessled.com/dev/). I am having trouble getting the lights to do what I am trying to tell them via Tasker, 2x UDP senders on my Android and a UDP sender on my PC. The lights respond correctly however through the MiiLight app.

I have been following wilfleaji's guide ([Problems with sending UDP packets (milight, limitlessled)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535502/problems-with-sending-udp-packets-milight-limitlessled/43449522#43449522)) step by step, but have not been able to successfully send any commands. At this stage I am simply trying to turn off all zones. 
I have a feeling where I am going wrong is the checksum; forgive me, I am a novice when it comes to this type of stuff. I could not figure out how (As per. wilfleaji) 31+0+0+8+4+1+0+0+0+1+0 = 54

I got the WifiBridgeSessionID: 28 00 00 00 11 00 02 F0 FE 6B 16 98 8E 50 AA 43 CD 00 01 E4 **00 00**
So ID1 = 00 and ID2 = 00

The Sequence number is **01**

The command is **31 00 00 08 04 02 00 00 00** = Light OFF

Zone number is **00** for all zones.

I worked out that the checksum should be the same as wilfleaji's, so **54**.

The end result: **80 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 01 00 31 00 00 08 04 02 00 00 00 00 00 54** which I send in "Packet Sender" and get the response 88 00 00 00 03 00 01 01 but the lights do not change.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?
Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.
Sincere regards,
Ryan Carmichael

Answer (score 0):

I was having precisely this problem, many angry evenings watching that same code ping back at me.

It turned out that it was because I had changed the 'Password' in the Milight app to a code other than the standard '0000'

The moment I changed this back to the standard '0000' it worked perfectly.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to keep my own passcode but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this.

Hope this fixes your problem too.